# How to create a database from a .sql file with postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I found a scientific paper on a database architecture. The authors gave a brief explanation of how to build the database from scratch but they are not clear enough for me since it is my first time working with PostgreSQL (have some experience with SQLite). This are the instructions from the authors:
"""
The entire MEAD data stored in ESAMP provenance is available in a PostgreSQL database. This format requires three steps to make use of: download the compressed SQL database dump file (.tar.gz format) from https://data.caltech.edu/records/hjfx4-a8r81; install PostgreSQL by following the instructions here; extract the .tar.gz file, which will yield a .sql file; follow the PostgreSQL documentation to create a new database from the .sql file. This will create a local copy of the database that we present in this work. The data can be browsed using the DBeaver user.
"""
I would like to know what steps are needed to o create a new database from the .sql file.

Thanks.

I have tried to use the \i command in psql to execute the commands and queries form the .sql file. The command works well and I can see a bunch of printed "ALTER TABLE" outputs. But after if I use \dt I get "Did not find any relations"

Comment: Assuming there were no errors and you haven't (or the script hasn't) reconnected to a different database they will be there. The most likely thing is that they are in a schema (a namespace for tables - like a directory holds files) that is not on your search-path. You can use `\dn` to list these and `\dt *.mytable` to search for "mytable" in all schemas. Find yourself a "getting started with PostgreSQL" guide online.